# Display upvote/downvote date on tooltip

Tags: feature-request, voting, up-votes, tooltips

I came across a question today which I had previously upvoted, however I was unsure when exactly this was.

Currently when you hover over a upvote arrow the tooltip displays:

> This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear (click
>   again to undo)

This is the same regardless of whether you have upvoted the post or not.

If you have upvoted/downvoted, would it be possible to display the date/time at which this was actioned?

I would find this useful as most times I come across a post I've voted on before is because I was having a similar problem in the past. Seeing exactly when this post first helped me would help me work out what problem it was before, and could help jog my memory.

Comment: Could you give a case where this information would be useful?

Comment: @RichardTingle Assume, e.g., a substantial edit in the answer. So it might be useful to see, whether I voted before or after that edit.

Comment: @RichardTingle I've edited my post. I would find it useful to see when it first helped me so I could relate it to what I was working on at the time, and therefore see where I'd implemented this, and how.

Comment: You could always find it in your voting history, but I agree it could be interesting to have it at your fingertips.

Comment: You might want to look at [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354573/on-the-timeline-view-for-questions-display-the-type-of-vote-and-when-it-was-cas/354588#354588), it's [tag:status-declined] though.

Answer (score 4):

*Regarding [Sirko's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197377/display-upvote-downvote-date-on-tooltip#comment624470_197377)*

Votes are locked after a certain period, only to be unlocked again after the question or answer has been edited. So if you want to change your vote, just try. If it works, it works. If it doesn't, it doesn't.

Regardless, I don't see why the date should matter in your voting behaviour. If you see a question or answer that you have upvoted in the past, but now you think it should be downvoted, just downvote it.

*Regarding OP's reason*

That does look like a valid use case. I agree with @AndersUP, the information is available on your profile, so it makes sense to let you skip the work of searching there and just display it on the question/answer itself.

Comment: *"Question votes are not locked"* Sure?

Comment: @Stijn Weird: I tried a question on main where my vote was a couple of days old. Couldn't, locked.

Comment: @michaelb958 I wasn't paying attention. The old questions I tried to remove my vote from also happened to have been edited after my vote had been cast.

Comment: @Stijn This answer has no relevance to the reason I believe it would be useful. Please see my post.

Comment: @Stijn That wasn't my comment.