# On the timeline view for questions, display the type of vote and when it was cast

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, voting, timeline

Looking at a timeline view, I'd like to understand what people were looking at when votes were cast.

The votes themselves should be anonymous with respect to who voted, but upvotes, downvotes, and bookmarks should show up in the timeline. In addition, a person undoing a vote should also show up. They should show up with respect to when they happened with other events, such as edits.

There is a way to see daily vote summaries that, once a day, display the number of upvotes, downvotes, and bookmarks. However, this doesn't let someone understand the state of a post when the vote was cast.

Comment: Knowing who voted at what time, especially for downvotes makes me able to figure out who downvoted, by correlating the reputation loss.

Comment: @Luuklag So you're going to search through hundreds or thousands of users to find out who voted? Plus, votes update in real-time. It's possible to sniff the data about vote changes through the websockets if you don't want to sit there. Technically, the information is available. This is just contextualizing it.

Comment: Does this answer your question?  [How to find out the time when a vote has been cast here on meta?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/988/how-to-find-out-the-time-when-a-vote-has-been-cast-here-on-meta/989)  There is also a useful SEDE query by Glorfindel there.

Comment: @Ollie No. I want the specific votes in the timeline view and I don't want to use SEDE because of the lag. In short, I want to take a question at any point in time and understand when votes were cast in relation to edits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We already provide a "daily summary" breakdown per-day for votes, which gives you an aggregate summary of the number of up- and down-votes that occurred on any given day. It is accessible to registered users by clicking on the "Show vote summaries" tab while in the timeline. We will not ever provide more detailed information than that to users.

Comment: That's disappointing. The data that I'm looking for is available, just not through official means. You can watch the websockets or use SEDE monthly dumps. I feel that it's important to be able to understand why a post is scored the way it is by being able to see the state of the post at the time votes are cast.