# Why not showing individual votes summary instead of daily votes summary in a post's timeline?

Tags: discussion, timeline

Particular a post's actions timeline by clicking the

[image]

option.

I can see all actions with dates and times except **votes**. It shows the daily votes summary,

[image]

Example: Link to [the post timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/384709/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries)

Is there a specific reason why we are not showing an individual votes summary with their date and time?

Comment: You posted partial screenshot for some reason. The votes are more to the right, in the "comment" column. For example, [Here is a full screenshot of the timeline of one of your answers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Uh0E.png).

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars where's vote exact time? I only see a daily summary.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt that's correct, timeline only showing daily summary, by design. To see exact times, only place is the user's profile.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars i have updated the question.

Comment: In theory this would let someone guess who downvoted someone - by looking at rep change. This would be *annoying* to do, but plausible

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, correct but we can show only date and time.

Comment: Can you state the reason why you want the system to show exact date and time? The point as stated above by Journeyman_Geek stands for the opposite opinion. Also if you want the system to show date and time tag it as [feature-request] too

Comment: My question is still: why not show? I wanted to understand, as per [commnet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385067/why-not-showing-individual-votes-summary-instead-of-daily-votes-summary-in-post#comment1284299_385067), I can understand, we can not show who voted but why we are not showing time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [On the timeline view for questions, display the type of vote and when it was cast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354573/on-the-timeline-view-for-questions-display-the-type-of-vote-and-when-it-was-cas) - declined just over 2 years ago.

Answer (score 7):

> Any specific reason why we are not showing individual votes summary with their date and time?

Yes, there are cases of posts with [hundreds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-about-a-vote-not-to-close-option-to-counter-the-vote-to-close) and even [thousands](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277369/a-terms-of-service-update-restricting-companies-that-scrape-your-profile-informa) of votes, so having thousands of items in the timeline will just clutter it and make it useless, impossible to see the other events.

Having only daily summary makes perfect sense to me, both showing useful information, without cluttering the timeline.

I really think it should stay this way.

To see full list of votes on a post, with the time, you can go to the post author's profile page and it would be in their "reputation" tab.

Comment: I seen that thousands of votes post's timeline, major are single vote per day, [ex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBoZs.png), but because of the daily summary, it shows the date only not the exact time. Make sense, an option is only author's profile.